# Not able to get the newly generated primary key from MySQL database using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` flag to obtan the newly generated primary key value after every insert in the database.

Here is the code snippet:

```
Connection conn = null;
conn = getDBConnection(); //Susseccfully returns a proper Connection object
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
String sql = "INSERT INTO ..."; //Proper error free INSERT query
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);//to obtain the new primary key
i = stmt.executeUpdate();//the value of i is always 1 :(
```

Not able to understand why this is happening. My driver is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

**EDIT:** The primary key's data tyoe is `BIGINT` in the DB and its the second column in the table.

Comment: here, You are getting number of rows updated. because `executeUpdate()` returns number of affected rows.

Comment: @JqueryLearner That is exactly my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`executeUpdate()` returns the number of affected rows.

Call `stmt.getGeneratedKeys()` to get a `ResultSet` with the generated keys:

```
long key = -1L;
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);//to obtain the new primary key
// execute statement
int affectedRows = stmt.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
// get generated key
if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
  key = rs.getLong(1);
}
```

Comment: What is 1 in `getInt(1)`?

Comment: OK so its not `rs.getInt(1)` but `rs.getLong(1)`. I think this is because the data type of the primary key is BigInt. But still I am not getting why 1?

Comment: @user3619962 It is a `ResultSet` object which just consists of 1 column with the generated keys. With `rs.getLong(1);` you get the value of the first column that contains the generated key.